# passing a value not defined in enum

Tags: objective-c, enums

I have a class named blender that has a `single instance variable, speed`. speed is of type enum `BlenderSpeed` defined as

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, BlenderSpeed)
{
 BlenderSpeedStir=1 ,
 BlenderSpeedCop=2 ,
 BlenderSpeedCrush=3
} ;
```

The main.m is as below.  Basically, I was expecting there to be a warning when I passed 5 as argument in the `setSpeed` message send since speed is only supposed to take on values 1, 2 and 3 per enum definition.

But I don't see any issues when I build and run the code.  The speed gets set to 5 without any issues.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
 @autoreleasepool {
    // insert code here...
    blender *myBlender = [[blender alloc] init] ;
    [myBlender setSpeed:2] ;
    NSLog(@"Current blender speeed = %lu",[myBlender speed]);
    [myBlender setSpeed:5] ;
    NSLog(@"Current blender speeed = %lu",[myBlender speed]);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the compiler simply doesn't check if the value 5 is part of the enum, instead it assumes that you as the programmer know what you are doing using an integer instead of an enum value. Objective-C is a dynamic language and not as strongly typed as other languages which may be why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks, Alex.  So, the same thing would result in an error in other languages (for e.g: C, C++, Java)?

Comment: I tested it in swift, which is a strongly typed language, and it would not let me do it; didn't test it in the ones you mention, but I imagine it would not work for those.